# Structuring a lengthy query on MySQL Workbench 8.0

Tags: mysql, laravel, mysql-workbench

I have the following query definition on MySQL Workbench:

```
use myDB;

select basic_product_id, 
    offer_id, 
    model_type, 
    model_id, 
    sum(initial_quantity) as initial_quantity,
    sum(quantity_on_offer) as quantity_on_offer,
    sum(sold_quantity) as sold_quantity,
    sum(remaining_quantity) as remaining_quantity,
    products_display_max,
    offers_display_max,
    minimum_purchase_quantity,
    maximum_purchase_quantity,
    pct,
    date_begins,
    date_ends,
    feature_from,
    feature_through,
    inactive
    
from (
    select *
    from (
        select 
            products.id as product_id,
            products.basic_product_id as basic_product_id,
            offers.id as offer_id,
            'App\\\Models\\\Category' as model_type,
            categories.id as model_id,
            products.initial_quantity,
            offers.total_quantity as quantity_on_offer,
            sum(sales.quantity) as sold_quantity,
            CASE 
                WHEN offers.total_quantity is not null
                THEN coalesce(offers.total_quantity, 0) - coalesce(sum(sales.quantity), 0)
                ELSE coalesce(products.initial_quantity, 0) - coalesce(sum(sales.quantity), 0)
            END as remaining_quantity,
            products.quantity_maximum_display as products_display_max,
            offers.quantity_maximum_display as offers_display_max,
            offers.minimum_purchase_quantity, offers.maximum_purchase_quantity,
            offers.pct,maximum_purchase_quantity 
            offers.date_begins, offers.date_ends,
            offers.feature_from, offers.feature_through,
            offers.inactive
            
        from
            products
            left join basic_products on  products.basic_product_id = basic_products.id
            left join categories on basic_products.categoria_id = categories.id
            join offers on offers.categoria_id = categories.id
            left join sales on sales.offer_id = offers.id AND sales.product_id = products.id AND sales.deleted_at is null
            
            group by products.id, offers.id
        
    ) as basic_products_offers_categories

    UNION   ALL

    select *
    from (
        select 
            products.id as product_id,
            products.basic_product_id as basic_product_id,
            offers.id as offer_id,
            'App\\\Models\\\Store' as model_type,
            stores.id as model_id,
            products.initial_quantity,
            offers.total_quantity as quantity_on_offer,
            sum(sales.quantity) as sold_quantity,
            CASE 
                WHEN offers.total_quantity is not null
                THEN coalesce(offers.total_quantity, 0) - coalesce(sum(sales.quantity), 0)
                ELSE coalesce(products.initial_quantity, 0) - coalesce(sum(sales.quantity), 0)
            END as remaining_quantity,
            products.quantity_maximum_display as products_display_max,
            offers.quantity_maximum_display as offers_display_max,
            offers.minimum_purchase_quantity, offers.maximum_purchase_quantity,
            offers.pct, maximum_purchase_quantity 
            offers.date_begins, offers.date_ends,
            offers.feature_from, offers.feature_through,
            offers.inactive
            
        from
            products
            left join basic_products on  products.basic_product_id = basic_products.id
            left join stores on basic_products.store_id = stores.id
            join offers on offers.store_id = stores.id
            left join sales on sales.offer_id = offers.id AND sales.product_id = products.id AND sales.deleted_at is null
            
            group by products.id, offers.id
        
    ) as basic_products_ofertas_stores

    UNION   ALL

    select *
    from (
        select 
            products.id as product_id,
            products.basic_product_id as basic_product_id,
            offers.id as offer_id,
            'App\\\Models\\\BasicProduct' as model_type,
            basic_products.id as model_id,
            products.initial_quantity,
            offers.total_quantity as quantity_on_offer,
            sum(sales.quantity) as sold_quantity,
            CASE 
                WHEN offers.total_quantity is not null
                THEN coalesce(offers.total_quantity, 0) - coalesce(sum(sales.quantity), 0)
                ELSE coalesce(products.initial_quantity, 0) - coalesce(sum(sales.quantity), 0)
            END as remaining_quantity,
            products.quantity_maximum_display as products_display_max,
            offers.quantity_maximum_display as offers_display_max,
            offers.minimum_purchase_quantity, offers.maximum_purchase_quantity,
            offers.pct,maximum_purchase_quantity 
            offers.date_begins, offers.date_ends,
            offers.feature_from, offers.feature_through,
            offers.inactive
            
        from
            products
            left join basic_products on products.basic_product_id = basic_products.id
            join offers on offers.basic_product_id = basic_products.id
            left join sales on sales.offer_id = offers.id AND sales.product_id = products.id AND sales.deleted_at is null
            
            group by products.id, offers.id
        
    ) as basic_products_ofertas_basic_products

    
) as basic_products_offers_quantities

group by basic_product_id, offer_id

order by basic_product_id
```

Which works fine but is very lengthy and error prone, so I was wondering if it´s possible to somehow arrange this in a more "modular" fashion by extracting partial queries to a saved .sql file and just calling it from the "main" query kinda like Laravel Blade @include directive. Something like the following:

```
use myDB;

select basic_product_id, 
    offer_id, 
    model_type, 
    model_id, 
    sum(initial_quantity) as initial_quantity,
    sum(quantity_on_offer) as quantity_on_offer,
    sum(sold_quantity) as sold_quantity,
    sum(remaining_quantity) as remaining_quantity,
    products_display_max,
    offers_display_max,
    minimum_purchase_quantity,
    maximum_purchase_quantity,
    pct,
    date_begins,
    date_ends,
    feature_from,
    feature_through,
    inactive
    
from (
    select *
    from (
        
     **Insert .sql file here for basic_products_offers_categories**
        
    ) as basic_products_offers_categories

    UNION   ALL

    select *
    from (

        **Insert .sql file for basic_products_offers_stores**
        
    ) as basic_products_offers_stores

    UNION   ALL

    select *
    from (

        
        **Insert .sql file for basic_products_offers_basic_products**

        
    ) as basic_products_offers_basic_products

    
) as basic_products_offers_quantities

group by basic_product_id, offer_id

order by basic_product_id
```

I read through the docs, but couldn´t find anything. By the way... the original query (and tables) are in spanish, and I might have missed something when I did the translation for this post, so "don´t try this at home!". Thanks.

Comment: You may, for example, create views from separate subqueries then use them in final query like they are tables.

Comment: Thanks @Akina. That´s exacly what I needed. Could you post it as an aswer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: It is a base, so I think that it is not enough for an answer. But you may create self-answer if you think that this may be useful for somebody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Akina suggestion, it is possible to work in a modular fashion on MySQL using Views. As I see it, Views are query based dynamic tables that can act as independent queries or as components to larger queries, making them a very useful tool when structuring a bigger project and are super easy to implement. Rather than trying to reproduce here what´s already been done, I would like to recommend the following tutorial:

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx
Cheers!